# Forgiveness instead of permission

Tags: discussion

EDDDITTT: Question: May I please be forgiven for telling this demon spawn to post his question on MSE?

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

EDIT:Apparently I made one of the possible correct calls. The 16 year old erased the contents of his MO question, about 37 minutes ago at this edit (they were restored). So this is more a question of cheating on some project or contest than actual curiosity. I shouldn't imagine he will post anything on MSE. I was not sure, I just did not want to spend hours writing explanations to a kid.

ORIGINAL:
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Email to me and then my reply:

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

> Hey! :) U have answered my question in this topic :
>   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115193/can-be-any-number But i don't
>   really get your solution :( I'm only 16, could you explain to me your
>   solution as elementary as you can?

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Hello, still entirely nameless person.
    I think the most responsible thing I can do is to encourage you to
register on MSE and post your question again as one of:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest
You should include a link to the original question on MO. You should also
explain your age and how, exactly, you came to be considering this
problem. Emphasize that you are looking for more detail at an elementary
level. There are plenty of professors and high school teachers who
have a good deal of experience explaining things at your level. Say
something about how your own mathematics teacher is unable to explain
this.

This way, you are likely to get several good answers, and you can
still request more detail.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, may I please be forgiven for telling this  demon spawn to post his question on MSE?

Comment: Yes. Whether to forgive you for putting the question into a comment instead of editing it into the body, that's another issue.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I retroactively obey, wise one.

Comment: By the way, I wonder whether you have noticed http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250249/integers-represented-by-the-polynomial

Comment: @GerryMyerson, interesting. Old John thought it was this kid he has been tracking. But that person uses multiple ID's anyway, so maybe the same. Certainly suggestive, the same method, sufficiently large and all.

Comment: No. You shall not be forgiven.

Comment: @MattN., I was afraid of that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, it is the same guy, he is on a chat room asking for more detail on x^2 + y^3 + z^6 representing numbers over 2012^2012, which tells me it is from a 2012 contest. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics

Comment: It is not easy to search the web for $x^2+y^3+z^6$, nor for $2012^{2012}$.

Comment: Why is the kid bad? Because he's cheating? How do you know it's cheating that's the reason for what he did? ("bad" <--- "demon spawn")